# Find subsets $A,B,C,D$ of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ such that $R = ((A \times B) \cup (C \times D)) − (D \times D)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R=\{(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,2),(4,3)\}$ be a collection of ordered pairs. Find subsets $A,B,C,D$ of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ such that $R = ((A \times B) \cup (C \times D)) − (D \times D)$.

I cannot solve this problem. My progress is that I think that $D=\{2\}$ or $\{4\}$ since if $D$ is the set of either $1$ or $3$ it will follow that $D \times D$ contains $(1,1)$ or $(3,3)$ which is impossible since $R$ contains $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$. Moreover, $D$ contains just one element since if $D$ contains both $2$ and $4$ the ordered pair $(4,2)$ would not be an ordered pair in $R$. This is pretty much all I can think of for myself and how to proceed is not clear to me.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $D$ is not the set $1$ or $3$. What you are trying to say is that $D$ can't CONTAIN $1$ or $3$.

Comment: I said ”the set of”, not ”the set” is that wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "the set of 1"?

Comment: Also $D\neq\{4\}$. Since $R$ contains no pair with 4 in its right component, the only way to have $D=\{4\}$ is by also setting $C=\{4\}$ and it is easy to see that with $D=C=\{4\}$ we cannot arrive to a solution.

Comment: There's no such subsets. Could there be a typo in the problem statement?

Comment: It is from the book
”Mathematical Proofs
A Transition to Advanced Mathematics”
By
Gary Chartrand, Albert D. Polimeni, Ping Zhang. I have copy pasted the problem from it, so I don’t think so.

Comment: @IAmMathing Books also can have typos.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in the book.
As you have deduced, $D$ is $\{2\}$ or $D$ is $\{4\}$.

Supoose $D=\{4\}$. Then $R\subset A\times B$ since there is nothing in $R$ of the form $(c, 4)$ (which are the only things possibly in $C\times D$). But then $2\in A, 3\in B$ but we have $(2,3)\notin R$.

Suppose $D=\{2\}$. Then $ \{ (1,1),(2,1), (3,3),(4,3)\}\subset A\times B$.  Then again $2\in A, 3\in B$ but we have $(2,3)\notin R$.

[image]